# only allow LAN connections to server

Tags: iptables

I would like to setup my new server (located on my LAN) to ALLOW ALL incoming and outgoing traffic from any other computer on my LAN, but DENY any connections from systems outside of the LAN. My question is how do I setup iptables to do this ?

Also,I would like to know if this would impact my ability to download files from the Internet on that server ? Would I still be able to download security updates for the server if I set things up this way ? As you may have guessed I am pretty new to all of this so please excuse my ignorance in advance.

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your LAN is 192.168.2.0/24. Run

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.2.0/24
```

It *seems* that that by default ufw allows outbound so this would not affect your ability to download files from the Internet. After these commands are executed run `sudo iptables -L -v -n` and post the output and I'll tell you for certain.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/firewall.html and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/ufw.8.html for more info.

Comment: I cannot post the entire output here because it is to large to include as a comment so I copied and pasted it to this pastebin link. http://pastebin.com/irDePsvS To be honest, I do not have a clue what I am looking at or know if this is correct, but I did follow your instructions and this is what I ended up with.

Comment: @Tim. Wow that is complicated. From what I can tell, though, your 2 goals are accomplished. However, is your LAN actually `192.168.2.0/24`? I was using that as an example. Also, have you attempted to make an outgoing connection to the Internet from the server?

Comment: My LAN IPs actually start at 192.168.2.1 and I put that IP in the firewall rule you listed and it shows up like that when I check the rule using this command **sudo ufw status** . However, in pastebin file the IP is shown differently so I am not sure which one is is actually working or if it's working at all. I am pretty sure what I am trying to do is a common task, but the lack of official documentation on the subject makes it quite difficult to implement.

Comment: @Tim In a simple network 192.168.2.1 is in the 192.168.2.0/24 subnet so I'm guessing it was converted to that. The links in my answer are the official documentation. When in doubt experiment.

Comment: If my default policy for the INPUT & OUTPUT chain is DENY, then i have to also create rule "to" not only "from" ? Because OP asked "I would like to setup my new server (located on my LAN) to ALLOW ALL incoming and outgoing"?

Answer (score 0):

Install Shorewall with the single interface example.  This can be handled with the policy file.

Answer (score 0):

Using IPtables are always best way to secure your server besides that you can also use TCP wrappers. As example in order to allow/deny access to ALL tcpwrappers services to ALL clients:

```
ALL : ALL
```

The above configuration on /etc/hosts.deny will deny access to all tcpwrappers services. However this line on /etc/hosts.allow will allow access to all tcpwrappers services with no restrictions. In order to deny sshd access from the IP 192.168.10.100 the following configuration can be used on /etc/hosts.deny :

```
sshd : 192.168.10.100
```

Specifically, in your case you can modify /etc/hosts.allow :

```
ALL: 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
```

I assume your LAN network is 192.168.1.0/24 in this case. ALL in hosts.allow allows all services provided by the server. Next you need to modify /etc/hosts.deny:

```
ALL: Deny
```

I usually use iptables and tcpwrappers altogether for maximum security on per machine level.

Answer (score -1):

Use a firewall, linux has Iptables built in:

http://www.netfilter.org/

Since it's pretty complex, I'd use a tool like GuardDog (KDE) to set it up. 
http://www.simonzone.com/software/guarddog/

Comment: I know I need a firewall and already have iptables. I just need to set it up correct which is why I asked here. Also, I do use a graphics enabled server (or w/e you call it) everything is command line only so installing an applik the guard dog app would be useless for me. Finally, I using Ubuntu 10.04-1 as the server and do only intend to have a few servers (mainly SSH, FTP, Webmin) installed so I do not need to worry about setting stuff up for Apache, Mysql, Php,... Just the basics.

Comment: Furthermore, my entire network is behind a NAT router (which has it's own firewall) so do I even need to worry about setting up the linux firewall in the first place if I do not explicit allow ports to be forwarded in my routers firewall ?